# PHP Pagination Div Showing Error Result

Tags: php, html, pagination

Hello i have a quick question.

This is the code

```
<div class="beta-pagination text-center">
<?php
 if($page > 1) {
    echo '<a href="search.php?page='. ($page - 1) .'&q='. $searchTerm .'"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>' . "\n";
     if($page > 2) {
   echo '<a href="#">...</a>';
    }
    echo '<a href="search.php?page=' . ($page - 1) . '&q='. $searchTerm .'">'. ($page - 1) .'</a>';
    } else {
     echo '<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>' . "\n";
     }
?>
<a href="#" class="is-active"><?php echo $page; ?></a>
<a href="search.php?page=<?php echo ($page + 1); ?>&q=<?php echo $searchTerm; ?>"><?php echo ($page + 1); ?></a>
<a href="#">...</a>
<a href="search.php?page=<?php echo ($page+1); ?>&q=<?php echo $searchTerm; ?>"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

I use this pagination div on one of my shopping website, and is working great if use this url "www.domain. com/search?q=shoes" website is displaying all of my products from database.

And when i press next page goes to "www.domain. com/search.php?page=2&q=shoes" and is perfect.

But the problem is when i want to display second page of products based on merchant.

For example if i go on `www.domain .com/search/search.php?brand=503` it display the results alright, but when press next page button it sends me to `www.domain .com/search.php?page=2&q=` and i need to go on `www.domain .com/search.php?page=2&brand=503`

Can someone please help me out with what should i add to my div code? a paste with the new code will be great! Thanks.

Comment: You have to add the `brand=503` in your url. Now you are only passing the page and `q` argument. You can try to create dynamic pagination depending of the previous params.

Answer (score 0):

You lose 'brand' when making url for href. For common case write such code to save input get string

```
$query = $_GET;
if(isset($query['page'])) unset($query['page']);
$query = http_build_query($query);
```

and replace `.'&q='`. by`.'&'.$query.`

Comment: Forgotten about function :) Edited the answer